# Incompatible File Format

Tags: php, zend-framework, fatal-error, incompatibletypeerror

I have an application on php with zend technology, when i am runs it live on the homepahe it shows this message:

> Fatal error: Incompatible file format: The encoded file has format major ID 5, whereas the Loader expects 4 in XXX\XX\Core\bootstrap.php on line 0

how runs it fine someone help me !

Comment: See [this](http://forums.kayako.com/threads/fatal-error-incompatible-file-format.24870/) thread: *To resolve the issue you are facing, please download ionCube encoded product files from your members ares area and upload them in the document root of the website. (Do not overwrite config and files folder)*

Comment: thanks for valuable reply sir... but i have already installed ioncube loader and it says  Loader Installed
The ionCube Loader version 4.4.1 for PHP 5.3 is already installed and encoded files should run without problems.  and problem not resolved

Answer (score 0):

Your code is encoded for wrong PHP's version. Decode and encode it to correct one.